# Storing values returning from a function in Java for Android

Tags: java, android

I have a function `getString(i,j)` returning string value for every i,j and I wish to store it in some data structure. Below is the code.

```
for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<16; j++)
     Log.d(TAG,this.objNew.getString(i,j));
```

`objNew` is the object helping to access `getString` function in another file. (this.objNew.getString(i,j)) returns a string value i.e. it will return 256 string values when executed in loop.

I tried `String[][] arr` i.e. `arr[i][j] = this.objNew.getString[i][j]`, but it didn't work.

Any ideas how can I store into some data structure and display the values.

Please suggest

Comment: Did you initialise the String[][] matrix before using it? More information would be great!

Comment: That would be, String[][] arr = new String[16][16] before trying to store values in it.

Comment: Yeah I had initialized it before using... but I guess its working now... looking more into it... Thanks for quick help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
int[][] ints=new int[16][16];
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<16;j++)
        ints[i][j]=objNew.getString[i][j];
```

Comment: Strings don't go in int arrays... :p

Comment: Hey I created a string integer and its working... thanks a ton... :D